# How to disable a Button in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have big problems with disabling a Button in ASP.net.
When i disable the button on client side, the button is enabled after postback.
When i disable the button on server side, i can't save a mask because the button is away.

How can i fix that?
The saving action is executed on the first Preload/PostBack.
Meaning that the second PostBack and everything after should not do the save process.

Also my Button is created new after every preload. How can i give this Button a fixed ID so that it is always the same object that i'm overwriting and on which i have acess.

in .cs:

```
    private void AddSaveButton()
    {
        ActionButton b = new ActionButton(GetString(6025));
        b.ID = "ButtonSave";
        b.ClientInstanceName = "ButtonSave";
        b.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        b.Click += new EventHandler(save_event);
        DivButton.Controls.Add(b);
    }
```

in aspx:

```
 <div runat="server" id="DivButton" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px; float: left">
```

ActionButton:

```
public class ActionButton : DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton
{
    public ActionButton(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.CssClass = "actionButton";
        this.CssPostfix = "actionButton";
        this.AllowFocus = false;
        this.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
        this.CausesValidation = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which stage you are disabling the button?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18653978/1185053) - but frankly I'm confused why you are creating your button in the `.cs` file rather than the `.aspx` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a `css-class` to everytime you create the button.

Doing that you can do something like below using `jQuery`

```
 $('.className').attr("disabled", true);
```

Using `javascript` will need to use [document.getElementsByClassName](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=881)

Comment: I can't use jQuery. Sorry.

Comment: You can't use `jQuery`? No, anyone can use jQuery. Sorry for you then!!. Try `Javascript` solution

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `javascript` to disable your button.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function disableBtn() 
    {
    document.getElementById("DivButton").disabled=true
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a fixed ID by using the property `ClientIDMode` and setting it to `Static`. But also, you can access to the control using JavaScript like in the example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function DoSomething() {
    alert('<%= Control.ClientID %>');
  }
</script>
```

More info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature

Comment: Sounds good, but i don't get how i can work this out on my button problem. My button code is in my post, can you pls give me a example on how i can set a static id and then acess this id after a preload?

Comment: If you set the property `ClientIDMode` of the button to `Static`, you can use directly the ID you stablished for this control (the control is renderer in HTML with the same ID you defined, without adding anything). I think I don't understand where is your problem.

Comment: what does that means?

Comment: That Static is only aviable since 4.0

Comment: f*#k me! that's true! sorry for my ignorance :(

Comment: You coudn't know that i'm using 3.5 ;) But thx for trying to help me :) (I i had 15 reputation points i woud give you a upvote)

Comment: take a look to this: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery

Comment: I also can't use jQuery. :/

Comment: Well, you can addapt the example to avoid jQuery selectors. There is not problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "my button is created after every preload" or "I can't save the mask".

If you want to affect the enabled status on postback you can do either of the following:

```
button.Enabled = false;
```

or

```
button.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: That is what i already tried.... and it didn't worked because my addbutton mathod (look in my post) is called by every Preload.
And everytime the button is pressed there is a preload...

Answer (score 1):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653343/how-to-disable-a-button-in-asp-net/18653978#comment27467779_18653742):

> my addbutton mathod (look in my post) is called by every Preload. And everytime the button is pressed there is a preload

Don't put the creation of the button in the `Pre_Load` put it in `Page_Load` with a check for `IsPostBack`.

Comment: It is already in the Page_Load (sorry i wroted that miss understanding) and i also tried to check for IsPostBack. The problem is that when i press the save button, the save action is first executed by the first PostBack. So it only shoud not be executed by the second postback.

Comment: Why aren't you creating your button in the `.aspx` file?

Comment: There is no purpose about that. But does that effect anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your button in the `Page_Init` event, if you want to add the button from the `.cs` file and can't place the button in the `.aspx` file, like below.

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddSaveButton();
}
```

Adding the button in the `Page_Init` would make it maintain its `State` during every post back.

Your method to add save button as it is...

```
private void AddSaveButton()
{
    ActionButton b = new ActionButton(GetString(6025));
    b.ID = "ButtonSave";
    b.ClientInstanceName = "ButtonSave";
    b.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    b.Click += new EventHandler(save_event);
    DivButton.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

Now, you can find the button from the page in your save_event and disable it like this...

```
protected void save_event(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActionButton b = (ActionButton)this.FindControl("ButtonSave");
    b.Enabled = false;
    //do your saving stuff here...
}
```

After this, button would be disabled on every postback.

**EDIT :**

Well, if you are adding this button from `.aspx` then you can directly set it to enabled false like below.

```
ButtonSave.Enabled = false;
```

instead of

<strike>ActionButton b = (ActionButton)this.FindControl("ButtonSave");</strike>

<strike>b.Enabled = false;</strike>

Comment: That sounded like a great idea but he is telling me that there is no definition for FindControls

Comment: @besnep there was a typo in the code. I have edited the answer now. The actual method name is `FindControl` and not _FindControls_.

Comment: Is the button added on the page correctly? And have you extended `ActionButton` from `Button` class? What is the purpose of `GetString(6025)` method?

Comment: I have added the button code from aspx. The GetString(6025) is for the driffrent languages.
The Button is shown and funktional correct when i debug.

Comment: Could you please tell the reference namespace for `ActionButton`? You can find it by pressing `F12` while placing the cursor on the `ActionButton` in the code. OR by right clicking and selecting `Go To Definition`.

Comment: shoud be HelpdeskOnline.
I have added the ActionButton in my Post.

Comment: (The button is added onto a div as you can see in my post. A Div can't be disabled) Because of that i added a real button to test but that is strange... He is setting the button to enabled = false but the button on the Page is still enabled :/

Comment: It isn't working anyway. :/ 
Also the AddButton get called by every postback